deepFace: No module named 'tensorflow.keras'
i try downgrading from tensorflow = 2.16.1 to 2.15.0. because when i run it with tensorflow = 2.16.1 i encountered tf-keras not found.
now i have tensorflow =2.15.0 , (Ubuntu). how can i solve this issue when importing deepFace.
2024-05-21 09:59:41.200746: E external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:9261] Unable to register cuDNN factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuDNN when one has already been registered
2024-05-21 09:59:41.200827: E external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_fft.cc:607] Unable to register cuFFT factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuFFT when one has already been registered
2024-05-21 09:59:41.236924: E external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc:1515] Unable to register cuBLAS factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuBLAS when one has already been registered
2024-05-21 09:59:41.316878: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:182] This TensorFlow binary is optimized to use available CPU instructions in performance-critical operations.
To enable the following instructions: AVX2 FMA, in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2024-05-21 09:59:42.404682: W tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc:38] TF-TRT Warning: Could not find TensorRT
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/qasim/Desktop/play.py", line 3, in <module>
    from deepface import DeepFace
  File "/home/qasim/deepface/lib/python3.11/site-packages/deepface/DeepFace.py", line 20, in <module>
    from deepface.modules import (
  File "/home/qasim/deepface/lib/python3.11/site-packages/deepface/modules/modeling.py", line 5, in <module>
    from deepface.basemodels import (
  File "/home/qasim/deepface/lib/python3.11/site-packages/deepface/basemodels/VGGFace.py", line 6, in <module>
    from deepface.modules import verification
  File "/home/qasim/deepface/lib/python3.11/site-packages/deepface/modules/verification.py", line 9, in <module>
    from deepface.modules import representation, detection, modeling
  File "/home/qasim/deepface/lib/python3.11/site-packages/deepface/modules/representation.py", line 9, in <module>
    from deepface.modules import modeling, detection, preprocessing
  File "/home/qasim/deepface/lib/python3.11/site-packages/deepface/modules/detection.py", line 11, in <module>
    from deepface.detectors import DetectorWrapper
  File "/home/qasim/deepface/lib/python3.11/site-packages/deepface/detectors/DetectorWrapper.py", line 5, in <module>
    from deepface.detectors import (
  File "/home/qasim/deepface/lib/python3.11/site-packages/deepface/detectors/MtCnn.py", line 3, in <module>
    from mtcnn import MTCNN
  File "/home/qasim/deepface/lib/python3.11/site-packages/mtcnn/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    from mtcnn.mtcnn import MTCNN
  File "/home/qasim/deepface/lib/python3.11/site-packages/mtcnn/mtcnn.py", line 37, in <module>
    from mtcnn.network.factory import NetworkFactory
  File "/home/qasim/deepface/lib/python3.11/site-packages/mtcnn/network/factory.py", line 26, in <module>
    from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, PReLU, Flatten, Softmax
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.keras'


Please post the error as text, not a screenshot.

Alright, updated

see source code on GitHub and file requirements.txt - there is tensorflow>=1.9.0 - maybe it needs version older than 2.0.0

in file requirements_local.txt you can see tensorflow==2.9.0 and keras==2.9.0 as two separate modules. Maybe you have to use 2.9.0 and you have to install keras on your own.

you should be able to import from tensorflow import keras if you have tf 2.15. if you cannot import it, then please run this code in python import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.__version__), i expect to see a different version. using virtual environments causes this problem often.
